# Remove all StructType columns from PySpark DataFrame

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a data frame `df` that reads a JSON file as follows:

```
df = spark.read.json("/myfiles/file1.json")
```

`df.dtypes` shows the following columns and data types:

> ```
> id – string
> Name - struct
> address - struct
> Phone - struct
> start_date - string
> years_with_company - int
> highest_education - string
> department - string
> reporting_hierarchy - struct
> ```

I want to extract only non-struct columns and create a data frame. For example, my resulting data frame should only have `id`, `start_date`, `highest_education`, and `department`.

Here is the code I have which partially works, as I only get the last non-struct column `department`'s values populated in it. I want to get all non-struct type columns collected and then converted to data frame:

```
names = df.schema.names

for col_name in names:
   if isinstance(df.schema[col_name].dataType, StructType):
      print("Skipping struct column %s "%(col_name))
   else:
      df1 = df.select(col_name).collect()
```

I'm pretty sure this may not be the best way to do it and I missing something that I cannot put my finger on, so I would appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: Almost dupe of [Selecting only numeric/string columns names from a Spark DF in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44066635/selecting-only-numeric-string-columns-names-from-a-spark-df-in-pyspark)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
cols_filtered = [
    c for c in df.schema.names 
    if not isinstance(df.schema[c].dataType, StructType) 
]
```

Or,

```
# Thank you @pault for the suggestion!
cols_filtered = [c for c, t in df.dtypes if t != 'struct']
```

Now, you can pass the result to `df.select`.

```
df2 = df.select(*cols_filtered)
```

Comment: thank you very much I used a NOT expression because isinstnace gave me only struct type :)   - Following worked for me. thank you very much for your help                                                                                     -  cols_filtered = [c for c in df.schema.names if not isinstance(df.schema[c].dataType, StructType)]   

df1 = df.select(*cols_filtered)

Comment: @Sameer I apologise for the sloppy answer. Thanks for the fix!

Comment: or you can do `cols_filtered = [c for c, t in df.dtypes if t != 'struct']` and avoid the call to `isinstance`

Comment: @pault - Interestingly the original solution works for me and new one does not. May be 'struct' is not a valid data type (dtypes) but that is how internally spark represents a structtype in schema. Comparing a data type against struct is not giving me desired results but checking for isinstance of  StructType is working. 'https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/package-frame.html. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @pault sorry for the delay df.dtypes do show struct when printing data types of schema