# filter on the pyspark dataframe schema to get new dataframe with columns having specific type

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, types

I want to create a generic function in pyspark that takes dataframe and a datatype as a parameter and filter the columns that does not satisfy the criteria. I am not very good at python and I am kind of stuck at the point from where I am not able to find how can I do that.
I have a scala representation of the code that does the same thing.

```
//sample data
val df = Seq(("587","mumbai",Some(5000),5.05),("786","chennai",Some(40000),7.055),("432","Gujarat",Some(20000),6.75),("2","Delhi",None,10.0)).toDF("Id","City","Salary","Increase").withColumn("RefID",$"Id")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
def selectByType(colType: DataType, df: DataFrame) = {
  val cols = df.schema.toList
    .filter(x => x.dataType == colType)
    .map(c => col(c.name))
  df.select(cols:_*)

}
val res = selectByType(IntegerType, df)
```

res is the dataframe that has only integer columns in this case the salary column and we have drop all the other columns that have different types dynamically.

I won't the same behaviour in pyspark but I am not able to accomplish that.

This is what I have tried

```
//sample data
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType, DoubleType
schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("firstname",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("middlename",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("lastname",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("id", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("gender", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("salary", IntegerType(), True), \
                     StructField("raise",DoubleType(),True) \
  ])
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType
data2 = [("James","","Smith","36636","M",3000,2.5),
    ("Michael","Rose","","40288","M",4000,4.7),
    ("Robert","","Williams","42114","M",4000,8.9),
    ("Maria","Anne","Jones","39192","F",4000,0.0),
    ("Jen","Mary","Brown","","F",-1,-1.2)
  ]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data2,schema=schema)
//getting the column list from schema of the dataframe
pschema = df.schema.fields
datatypes = [IntegerType,DoubleType]  //column datatype that I want.
out = filter(lambda x: x.dataType.isin(datatypes), pschema)  //gives invalid syntax error.
```

Can someone help me out in terms of what is the thing that I am doing wrong. Scala code only passes single datatype but I as per my use case I want to handle scenario in which we can pass multiple datatypes and we get the dataframe with required columns of that specified datatypes.

Initially if someone can give any idea for how can I make it work for single datatype then I can give it a try to see if I can do that same for multiple datatypes.

Note : Sample data for scala and pyspark is different as I copied the Pyspark sample data from somewhere just to speed the operation as I am just concerned about the final output requirement.

Comment: Use `isinstance(obj, type)` to check the type of field : `cols = [F.col(f.name) for f in df.schema if isinstance(f.dataType, dataType)]`

Comment: Or using `df.dtypes` with : `cols = [F.col(c) for c, t in df.dtypes if t in ("int", "string")]`

Comment: that works And I am able to get the columns. Just can you tell me how I can use that columns to select that columns from dataframe in pyspark.. Also you can post this as a answer and I can accept that as it helped me.

Comment: FYI you can also check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44066635/selecting-only-numeric-string-columns-names-from-a-spark-df-in-pyspark)

Comment: Just do `df.select(*cols)` as you would do in scala :)