# How to select columns in PySpark which do not contain strings

Tags: pyspark

I had the problem on how to remove the columns with strings in Pyspark, keeping only, numerical ones and timestamps.

This is how I did it.

I had this:

```
full_log.printSchema()

    root
     |-- ProgramClassID: integer (nullable = true)
     |-- CategoryID: integer (nullable = true)
     |-- LogServiceID: integer (nullable = true)
     |-- LogDate: timestamp (nullable = true)
     |-- AudienceTargetAgeID: integer (nullable = true)
     |-- AudienceTargetEthnicID: integer (nullable = true)
     |-- ClosedCaptionID: integer (nullable = true)
     |-- CountryOfOriginID: integer (nullable = true)
     |-- DubDramaCreditID: integer (nullable = true)
     |-- EthnicProgramID: integer (nullable = true)
     |-- ProductionSourceID: integer (nullable = true)
     |-- FilmClassificationID: integer (nullable = true)
     |-- ExhibitionID: integer (nullable = true)
     |-- Duration: string (nullable = true)
     |-- EndTime: string (nullable = true)
     |-- LogEntryDate: timestamp (nullable = true)
     |-- ProductionNO: string (nullable = true)
     |-- ProgramTitle: string (nullable = true)
     |-- StartTime: string (nullable = true)
```

**This will get the list of column names to filter**

```
no_string_columns = [types[0] for types in full_log.dtypes if types[1] != 'string']
```

**Perform the final selection**

```
full_log_no_strings = full_log.select([*no_string_columns])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting only numeric/string columns names from a Spark DF in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44066635/selecting-only-numeric-string-columns-names-from-a-spark-df-in-pyspark)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the schema object of the dataframe:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

string_columns = [column.name for column in full_log.schema if column.dataType != StringType()]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below logic for this use case.

- Step:1 Finding the columns which are string as datatype .
- Step:2 remove those columns list
- Step:3 apply your logic

**Code snippet :**

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType
data2 = [("James","","Smith","36636","M",3000),
    ("Michael","Rose","","40288","M",4000),
    ("Robert","","Williams","42114","M",4000),
    ("Maria","Anne","Jones","39192","F",4000),
    ("Jen","Mary","Brown","","F",-1)
  ]

schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("firstname",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("middlename",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("lastname",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("id", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("gender", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("salary", IntegerType(), True) \
  ])
 
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data2,schema=schema)
df.printSchema()
df.show(truncate=False)
columnList = [item[0] for item in df.dtypes if item[1].startswith('string')]
print(columnList)
df1 = df.drop(*columnList)
display(df1)
```

Screen shot:

[image]